# Отследить все запросы к базе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Суть проблемы: есть скрипт огромный, написанный мною, но использующий множество функционала из фремворка CMS(prestashop).
Сам по себе процесс работы скрипта прост, берётся список товаров, и к нему по порядку применяется одна и так же обработка.
При его работе чрез mytop я наблюдаю нагрузку на базу, разными запросами. Чтоб мне понять где капать, мне надо запустить один цикл, и проследить ВСЕ запросы к базе, и их последовательность. 
Есть ли какое-нибудь решения, чтоб я запустил скрипт, он отработает за пять секунд, и я получу список отправленных запросов к базе в процессе.

ЗЫ. Так как это все нужно получить именно с живого сайта, вариант вставить в классы обработчика запросов, дебагер, не подходит, так как туда просто напросто налетит куча не актуальной для меня информации.

Comment: Это называется General Log. И располагается в настройках MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "general_log%";
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

С помощью первой команды вы узнаете где лежит файл логов, со второй его включаете, все запросы будут хранится в этом файле. После завершения выключите логирование   командой

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
```